How to add testcase start time and end time in allure.nunit?
We are currently using NUnit version 4.1.0 and Allure.NUnit version 2.11.0, with over 500 test cases in our framework. During our daily regression tests, we frequently encounter a high number of test case failures, which makes it challenging to track the sequence of these test cases.
To address this, we would like to include the start and end times of test cases in the Allure step reports. This would greatly facilitate tracking and identifying the sequence of test cases.
Could you please guide us on how to add start and end times to the Allure steps in our test cases?
